# Create a function that takes a module as string and displays all functions in it

Tags: python

I am on Windows 7 (x64) using python 2.7.13 (x64). I am trying to create a function to display functions in a module. Here is what I tried.

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
# from sys import argv
# import sys
import importlib

def see(module_here):
    print("Functions in " + module_here + " module")
    importlib.import_module(module_here)
    a1 = dir(module_here)
    for i,v in enumerate(a1):
        print(str(i) + ") " + v)
see('sys')
```

I am not getting the desired result of "printing functions in sys module'. Instead it is printing functions associated with the string 'sys'. The result would have been the same if I were to use `see('this_does_not_exist')`.

I would be grateful if some python user/expert help me correct the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you call:

```
importlib.import_module(module_here)
```

but don't do anything with the result. The correct code should be:

```python
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
# from sys import argv
# import sys
import importlib

def see(module_here):
    print("Functions in " + module_here + " module")
    result = importlib.import_module(module_here)
    a1 = dir(result)
    for i,v in enumerate(a1):
        print(str(i) + ") " + v)
see('sys')
```

Mind however that this will print all **elements** in `sys`, not only the functions. You will need to do additional filtering to print only functions.

You could use - as @Vincenzzzochi says - the [`inspect.is_function`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction) to check if it is a function:

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
# from sys import argv
# import sys
import importlib
import inspect

def see(module_here):
    print("Functions in " + module_here + " module")
    result = importlib.import_module(module_here)
    a1 = dir(result)
    for i,v in enumerate(f for f in a1 if inspect.isfunction(f)):
        print(str(i) + ") " + v)
see('sys')
```

Comment: The OP can use the inspect module to get specifically functions via `im_func` descriptor, or use the `isfunction()` function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html:

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi: thanks for the suggestion. Indeed. Or one can use the `inspect.is_function` method. I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes, I corrected my comment to reflect this as well

Comment: (Willem, to enable syntax highlighting, in combination with bolding, use `<pre><code>..</code></pre>`. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260441/2564301)

Comment: @RadLexus: many thanks for this. I already checked the markdown source after your edit. +1.

Comment: As an aside, `inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)` returns a list of tuples of `(function_name, function_obj)`, in case anyone reading this ever needs something like that

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem for the answer. I realized I could also use `__import__` instead of `importlib.import_module`

Comment: @Stat-R: indeed, that is also explained in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) :).